# Turning a number negative in Verilog

Tags: binary, verilog

When you have a `binary number`, `A = 5'b00100`, and you get the negative `version` of it, `B`.

```
 reg signed [4:0] A, B;
 B = -A;
```

What does this do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll create the twos complement of the number: flip the bits and add one!

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Answer (score 0):

in the above case if both A/B are declared as 'signed', then the simple logic of 
B = -A should work and i tried in a simple case and it works. Verilog already does everything in 2's complement.